# Lead and lag issue using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, lead

I have a data frame with data that looks like this that has 365 rows reflecting the calendar year. I am trying to shift the county name columns up by one row. The data frame doesn't contain any missing values.

[image]

I tried using the following code to shift it, but the resulting table has values that are all NA.

```
covid_shift <- covid_pivot %>% 
mutate(Maricopa = lag(Maricopa), Cook = lag(Cook), Harris = lag(Harris))
```

[image]

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Since `covid_pivot` is grouped by date, and each of these groups has one row, the lead and lag functions return NA.

Try:

```
covid_shift <- covid_pivot %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Maricopa = lag(Maricopa), Cook = lag(Cook), Harris = lag(Harris))
```

You might also consider using `across()`

```
covid_pivot %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(across(-date, ~lag(.x)))
```